# Customize the "Share" dialog

Tags: item, popup, share

Can we add more options in the default popup for "Share" in SharePoint?

For example, an end date for the sharing?

Comment: No, you could use a workflow to remind you to disable sharing

Comment: that mean we cannot custom the share popup layout / add option ?

Comment: You can use code to customize anything you want, SharePoint does not have "end of sharing date" functionality out of the box, so you have to code that as well.